# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'BasicLSTMCell'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got the value error when I ran the recurrent neural network tensorflow code for a simple classification task on mnist dataset. I could not figure out what is wrong with the code. Seems to me everything is right.  Help wanted! thank you!

My tensorflow version is 0.12.1

Here is the message I got:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'BasicLSTMCell'
```

Below is the tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# set random seed for comparing the two result calculations
tf.set_random_seed(1)

# this is data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

# hyperparameters
lr = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 128

n_inputs = 28   # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_steps = 28    # time steps
n_hidden_units = 128   # neurons in hidden layer
n_classes = 10      # MNIST classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Define weights
weights = {
    # (28, 128)
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    # (128, 10)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    # (128, )
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    # (10, )
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes, ]))
}


def RNN(X, weights, biases):
    # hidden layer for input to cell
    ########################################

    # transpose the inputs shape from
    # X ==> (128 batch * 28 steps, 28 inputs)
    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])

    # into hidden
    # X_in = (128 batch * 28 steps, 128 hidden)
    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']
    # X_in ==> (128 batch, 28 steps, 128 hidden)
    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])

    # cell
    ##########################################

    # basic LSTM Cell.
    if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    else:
        lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)
    # lstm cell is divided into two parts (c_state, h_state)
    init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)

    # unpack to list [(batch, outputs)..] * steps
    if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        outputs = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2]))    # states is the last outputs
    else:
        outputs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1,0,2]))
    results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']    # shape = (128, 10)

    return results


pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # tf.initialize_all_variables() no long valid from
    # 2017-03-02 if using tensorflow >= 0.12
    if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    else:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    step = 0
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape([batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs])
        sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs,
            y: batch_ys,
        })
        if step % 20 == 0:
            print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs,
            y: batch_ys,
        }))
        step += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
if int((tf.__version__).split('.')[1]) < 12 and int((tf.__version__).split('.')[0]) < 1:
        lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    else:
        lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)
```

with just

```
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
```

It seems that this is the correct line in both versions.